# Dual Boot GRUB2

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot

I just installed EasyBCD for my dual boot laptop (Windows7 and Ubuntu 14.04). Everything works great, however if I choose the Ubuntu option on loading, the next screen it takes me to is GRUB2 with the options of Windows and Ubuntu. How do I bypass that screen so that it bypasses the Linux bootloader and goes right into Ubuntu

When I edited the grub file as suggested and run a `sudo update grub` this is what I get:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda3
done`
```

When I restart it, the grub still appears as the same.

Comment: How about and just remove EasyBCD... you don't need it.

Comment: Because the grub2 is not loading to windows properly. Every attempt I made at fixing the grub has not resolved the issue i was experiencing. When I installed EasyBCD, it gave better results.

Comment: And I dont even know why this is being down voted in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the values that are in `etc/default/grub` to look like these:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: That didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way of bypassing GRUB2 (or any other Linux bootloader) via EasyBCD. Most probably EasyBCD is not a universal bootloader and it works by [chain loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_loading) into GRUB2.

Your best bet is to try and make GRUB2 timeout on the Ubuntu entry immediately as [Jonyburd's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140247/26909) is suggesting. I believe you should look into why it failed.

Comment: How can i find out why it failed?

Comment: @ryekayo The first place to look would be `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which is created by `update-grub`. You need to make sure that the Ubuntu entry has `set timeout 0` as expected.

Comment: I see two blocks of code as to where to set timeout I will add that to my question.

Comment: @ryekayo You should _not_ edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` by hand. Any edits you make will be silently clobbered the next time you run `update-grub` or update the GRUB2 package (which causes `update-grub` to be run). Restrict your edits to `/etc/default/grub` and files in `/etc/grub.d`

Comment: Ok then how do i set the timeout as mentioned

Comment: @ryekayo This string of comments is getting too long. You may want to [continue this in the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running in a similar problem, where setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` didn't help:

In my case the grub [os-prober](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Script_Descriptions) had overwritten the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to 10, whatever value I might have set in `/etc/default/grub`.

If you don't need the other OS entries in grub (because you have two chained bootloaders as here or your BIOS already has kind of a boot menu) disabling the os-prober in `/etc/default/grub` might help:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

If you need these entries though, you probably have to edit `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries